# How to add a new file in zend public folder and route it?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a index.php file under public folder in zend framework and creat some variable that used for my site
I created a file jsvar.php 
I don't want to include index.php file in jsvar.php to access the variable of
I want to route this jsvar file that I can easily access all variable of index.php in jsvar.php file rather to use include'index.php'

Answer (score 0):

You could make index.php a class with properties and/or constants (wich will also initialize the zend framework core) and access through namespaces:

```
namespace MyApp;
class Index
{
    const MY_VAR = 'shikaka';
    //rest of your code here
}
```

And then:

```
namespace MyApp;
class Jsvar
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        var_dump(Index::MY_VAR);
    }
}
```